# React - Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-loading-overlay' in 'F:\htdocs\....'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader

I want to implement react-loading-overlay in react for full page loaders.

Tried doing following things:

[image]

So I tried to install react-overlay-loading but it still shows me the error as above.

What's getting wrong here ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a module which is called [react-loading-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay-ts) which you can get by installing the package by using the command:

`npm i react-loading-overlay-ts`

This should install the required package.